# How to download bitcoin blockchain without core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, synchronization

I tried to download the entire blockchain using bitcoin-core but i took about 9 days and eventually gone corrupted and i had to delete and restart. Any source to download through torrent or regular browser download?

Answer (score 3):

If you torrent or otherwise download the blockchain but do not validate the data received, then you will be unable to know whether or not the data received is valid. This means you could easily download a chain which has been altered by an attacker, to include fake transactions, remove legitimate transactions, etc. You would have no way to know.

This is the reason that bitcoin-core takes some time to download *and validate* the chain: it is the only way to trustlessly know the current state of the network.

Note that bitcoin-core works most efficiently when it downloads the chain data as it goes. If you download a torrent of the chain and then attempt to validate using that, it will take even longer (you'll need to wait for the full download, and then the full validation, rather than doing parts of each in parallel).

I'm not aware of any software that can perform these validation steps more efficiently than bitcoin-core. You could try increasing the `-dbcache` option if you have under-utilized RAM. You could also try syncing to an SSD instead of an HDD, if you aren't already.